# Spaces in multi characters variable name in pandoc export to docx

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm writing a Haskell program to export some mathematics formula to `docx` and I have noted that variable names with multiple character are written with a blank white space between each letter and I don't understand why ?

My basic code is :

```
import Text.Pandoc
import Data.Map (fromList)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main = do
  document <- writeDocx WriterOptions{ writerStandalone=False
                                     , writerReferenceDocx=Nothing
                                     , writerUserDataDir=Nothing
                                     , writerHighlight= False
                                     }  pandoc
  B.writeFile "document.docx" document

pandoc = Pandoc ( Meta {unMeta = fromList []})
                           [ Para  [Str "A small Math example"]
                           , Plain [Math InlineMath "A_e = var + 5"]
                           , HorizontalRule
                           ]
```

and the result is :

[image]

and I would like to get :

[image]

I tried to modify the string defining my equation  to

```
Math InlineMath "A_e = {var} + 5"
```

but It didn't change anything

I also tried :

```
Math InlineMath "A_e = \\{var\\} + 5"
```

But It gave :

[image]

**Do you know how to remove these boring white spaces ?**

Comment: this seems like a bug in the pandoc docx writer. if it still occurs in the newest pandoc version, you should [report it](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues). also, you might want to use the [builder functions](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Builder.hs) instead of writing the data structures by hand...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually [texmath](https://github.com/jgm/texmath) that takes care of the latex->omml conversion (OMML is the xml format that docx uses). So you should post a bug there.