# Can't open Odt file generated from Pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc, libreoffice

I tried to generated a basic `odt` file with a mathematic formula with the Haskell `pandoc` library to verify if the problem described with `docx` documents in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228608/spaces-in-multi-characters-variable-name-in-pandoc-export-to-docx) is the same with odt files.

However, when I execute this code :

```
import Text.Pandoc
import Data.Map (fromList)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Set as Set

main = do
  document <- writeODT   WriterOptions{ writerStandalone=False
                               , writerReferenceODT=Nothing
                               , writerUserDataDir=Nothing
                               , writerExtensions=plainExtensions
                               }  pandoc
  B.writeFile "document.odt" document

pandoc = Pandoc ( Meta {unMeta = fromList []})
                           [ Para  [Str "A small Math example"]
                           , Plain [Math InlineMath "A_e = \\{var\\} + 5"]
                           , HorizontalRule
                           ]


plainExtensions = Set.fromList
  [ Ext_table_captions
  , Ext_implicit_figures
  , Ext_simple_tables
  , Ext_multiline_tables
  , Ext_grid_tables
  , Ext_latex_macros
  , Ext_fancy_lists
  , Ext_startnum
  , Ext_definition_lists
  , Ext_example_lists
  , Ext_intraword_underscores
  , Ext_blank_before_blockquote
  , Ext_blank_before_header
  , Ext_strikeout
  ]
```

The generated `odt` file can't be opened with libreoffice. When the file is opening, the following error message appear :

```
Format error discovered in the file in sub-document content.xml at 2,0(row,col)
```

**Is there something I made wrong with my Haskell code ? Or is it a Pandoc bug ?**

**Is there a trick to open the odt file nevertheless ?**

Comment: does it work without the `Math` element?

Comment: No, I removed the Math element but the error remain the same!

Answer (score 0):

If the haskell is compiling without error, it should be well-formed pandoc, which means that any error in the document is most likely a bug in the ODT writer. You should submit a bug to the github issue tracker.